# How to Invoke multiple controls in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke, begininvoke, invokerequired

I have a C# program seems stuck at random time, and after a random while it recovered itself! When it stuck, I can see the memory growth, and when it recover, the memory usage just drops to normal. The CPU usage seems normal all the way and there is no files is written or read (as designed).

The program calls an external (3rd party) DLL function to communicate with hardware, and updates the UI from the DLL's callback which running on a different thread. I have checked the code and found nothing suspicious apart from the following code (redacted):

```
private void Func(StructType para) {
    if (labelA.InvokeRequired) {
        labelA.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => Func(para)));
        return;
    }
    if (labelB.InvokeRequired) {
        labelB.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => Func(para)));
        return;
    }
    labelA.Text = para.A;
    labelB.Text = para.B;
}
```

I wonder if this is a proper way of update the UI element from another thread? If not, how to revise it?

In fact, I invoke 6 labels and another form (optionally). It seems working fine for most time but occasionally stuck. I can't post all code here for obvious reason, but just trying to troubleshot from where I doubt most.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Could be deadlock, the UI thread is doing something else (use Debug > Windows > Threads to diagnose).  Or you are calling BeginInvoke() far too often so the UI thread can't do anything else but handle the invokes, 50 times per second is plenty good enough for human eyes.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, there are also other functions call Invoke to other controls. The 3rd party SDK's sample code was written the same, but only one Invoke per function. I adapted the code and found I need to update multiple labels at same time, that's why I put multiple Invokes. Would you please suggest some correct way of doing so?

Comment: Another question is, if it causes deadlock, how come it resume itself for no reason at somepoint? The callback in my application should be 30 calls per second for one function and another 30 calls per second and another various calls per various second. The first one updates 6 labels and another full screen form (for showing an image on the screen), second updates a picturebox, and the last updates a richtextbox. When it stuck, it waits various time and start "flushing buffer" and will stuck again at various time before the buffer is flushed, and then in a loop :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to individually check each each control to determine if you need to invoke it - there is only one UI thread, thus, that check is only useful once. Keep in mind - modifying any UI component is almost certain to cascade into a whole bunch of other reads/writes to other UI components; as a result of that, you have to make the assumption that if you are touching *any* UI object, you have to assume you're touching *all* UI components.

With that in mind, I'd recommend you perform your invoke check once, and I recommend performing the check and invoke on the parent control of both labels.

Assuming `this` refers to the class that is the parent to both those labels, I would modify your code as follows:

```
private void Func(StructType para) {
    if (this.InvokeRequired) {

        // Elide the explicit delegate declaration; it's not necessary.
        this.BeginInvoke( Func(para) );

        // Elide the return statement - multiple returns are messy, and in this case, easily removed.
    }
    else {
       labelA.Text = para.A;
       labelB.Text = para.B;
   }
}
```

Be aware that `InvokeRequired` returns false if the object is disposed, even if the calling thread is not the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks. It won't be disposed for sure. I haven't tried to Invoke on the parent, i.e., the Form, but will it cause problems if multiple callback functions tries to Invoke the Form at the same time? Also, who can explain why the down vote? Thanks!